# DELPHI How to copy .txt file and rename

Tags: delphi

I need to copy a **.txt** file and rename it.

I am only a beginner, Please help me.

any suggestions and comments will do. THANKS in advance. :)

Comment: @justine Different Delphi versions have different facilities available. We don't know ow what version you use. I removed your spurious version tabs which simply listed 4 randomly chosen versions. Your question is poor and you have not edited it to address concerns raised in comments. Might I recommend the [help] so you get a clearer understanding of how this site works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are numerous ways to copy a file from one location to another, but the most straight-forward method is by using the [`CopyFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx) method, located in the `Winapi.Windows` unit...

```
CopyFile('C:\OriginalFile.txt', 'D:\NewFile.txt', False);
```

Comment: I have question sir @Jerry.. for what purpose is the FALSE statement?

Comment: According to the documentation which I linked in my answer, it's "Fail if Exists". Which means, `False` will overwrite a file if it already exists, and `True` will make the function fail if it exists.

Comment: This code ignores error checking. If the copy fails the program will continue, oblivious to the failure. On modern Delphi IOUtils unit has cross platform functionality for file copying.

Comment: thank you so much Sir @JerryDodge :)

Comment: how to do that sir @DavidHeffernan? I am a beginner sir..

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation? Have you done that yet? Does it describe how errors are signaled.

Comment: sir @JerryDodge I already try your code but this is what I need
 `dir := getCurrentDir+'/sample.txt';
CopyFile(dir, 'D:\smaple_backup.txt', False);`
but an error occured. any solution sir?

Comment: @justineyeojsonBarcelo That's an entirely different question. You don't mention any of this in your question above.

Comment: What was the error after you tried Jerry's suggestion? CopyFile expects a PAnsiChar (it does in Delphi 7). Try CopyFile(Dir),PChar('D:\Sample_Backup.txt'),false);

Answer (score 12):

Cross-platform solution

```
uses System.IOUtils;    
TFile.Copy('file.txt','anotherfile.txt');
```

Answer (score 1):

While you have already accepted an answer I wanted to expand slightly. The following is Delphi 7 but it likely to be similar in other versions. Either way it might point you in the right direction.

Two methods, the first is the simplest while the 2nd has a bit more error checking.

**Method 1 - Minimal Error Checking**

```
Procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  OldFile, NewFile: String;
Begin
  OldFile := 'Some file'; 
  NewFile := 'Some other file';

  If FileExists(OldFile) Then
  Begin
    If CopyFile(PChar(OldFile), PChar(NewFile), true) Then
      ShowMessage('Yay, file copied file')
    Else
      ShowMessage('Doh, file already exists!');
  End;
End;
```

**Method 2 - Slightly better Error Checking**

```
Procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  OldFile, NewFile: String;
Begin
  OldFile := 'Some file';
  NewFile := 'Some other file';
  If FileExists(OldFile) Then
  Begin
    Try
      If CopyFile(PChar(OldFile), PChar(NewFile), true) Then
        ShowMessage('Yay, file copied file')
      Else
        ShowMessage('Doh, file already exists!');
    Except
      On E: Exception Do
        ShowMessage(E.ClassName + ' Something really screwed up: ' + E.Message);
    End;
  End;
End;
```

Method 1 copies the file from Oldname to Newname and displays a message indicating success or failure.

Method 2 does the same but will trap exceptions raised just in case everything turns to custard.

I hope that helps you. Being a beginner it can be very overwhelming and sometimes you just need a helping hand.

Comment: All of your error handling is completely bogus. All of it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's simplistic, I agree, but how is it bogus? Tested with Delphi 7 (which I use) and it worked - unless I was having a bad typing day. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Method 1, many more failure modes than file already existing. Method 2, what is going to raise an exception? Nothing.

Comment: I accept your criticism @Davidheffernan, however I did state it's Minimal. Perhaps the term "Error Checking" was a poor choice of words as it reports if exists only. Regarding exceptions, are you saying that an exception can never occur under any circumstance in this situation? In which case method 1 would suffice as it is simply an expansion of the accepted answer.

Comment: Method 1 is wrong because the code can fail for many other reasons. GetLastError code will provide the reason for failure.

Comment: @Davidheffernan I agree, it can fail for many other reasons. The asker has stated they are a beginner and seasoned programmers sometimes forget how overwhelming it can all be. Documentation can be confusing without knowledge of terms used etc. Starting simple and gaining an understanding and then expanding to create bulletproof code comes with experience. An answer was accepted already and I was simply showing a very simplistic method for copying a file. The questioner simply needs a starting point imo. :)

Comment: Teaching them the wrong way to do things is not helpful though. That's my opinion.

Comment: the reason is you both only have different way to teach, but both of you are still helpful. :)